# UITableView with text and images: mixed up in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a small problem, which seems to be really classic (mixed up cells when reused by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier) but I have already looked at similar questions and can't find an answer.

So, classic context: I have a `UITableView` with protype cells in the storyboard, one with an image (asynchronously fetched) and one with a UITextView.

Let's focus on the text cells as I get problems on both and so we know the network is not the cause.

When I scoll down and up again, cells get mixed up. I think it is because I set the text value according to my data inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function but I'm not sure.

Here are my cells in my example:

```
---------------
| 1. "TEXT1"  |
---------------
|             |
| 2. IMAGE2   |
|             |
---------------
| 3. "TEXT3"  |
---------------
| 4. "TEXT4"  |
---------------
|             |
| 5. IMAGE5   |
|             |
---------------
```

I scroll all the way down, everything is fine. When I bounce at bottom, cells 3 and 4 are reloaded (I put a NSLog in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`function). First cell 4 is reloaded, then cell 3 (according to the log).
The problem is, cells 3 and 4 both end up with "TEXT3" as value ! I mean, if I `NSLog` the value I give to the UITextField.text in the function, they don't have the same text value, but on the simulator's screen, they have.. ?

Here is my code:

```c
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Getting data for row from indexPath
    Data *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    if (data.type == 1) { // Text type
        cellIdentifier = @"TextCell";
    }
    else if (data.type == 2){
        cellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Getting various cell elements

    if (data.type == 1) {
        // Text is 1000
        UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[tableView viewWithTag:1000];
        textView.text = data.text;
    }
    else if (data.type == 2){
        //STUFF FOR PHOTO TYPE OF DATA
    }

    return cell;
}
```

By the way, it can be useful to say that I get this error in the simulator on iOS6 but not on iOS7 (but maybe that's just different memory management..)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: check the data.type see if it is not 1 or 2

Comment: thanks, I already did that. I'm starting to guess that my problem is that the `UITextView` I get to change the text value is not linked to the specific cell, since I get it with `[tableView viewWithTag]` ??

Comment: I actually fixed it by doing [cell viewWithTag:1000] rather than [tableView viewWithTag:1000] which gives me the right UITextView to change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution myself by testing...
My problem was that to access the text view in my prototype cell, I gave it a tag in the storyboard.

But then, when I wanted to edit the text in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I was using `[tableView viewWithTag:myTag]`  while I should have been using `[cell viewWithTag:myTag]` , so I was editing, I guess, the last one?

All in all, it's good now.. And I was just looking at the wrong place since I was SURE it was about reusing the wrong cell or smth..
If anyone knows why it didn't happen in ios7, please share !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and this is how I solved it.

In my CustomTableViewCell, I had the init method where I was setting values for labels etc.

so I added this condition in init.

code:

- (void) initWithCellLabelString : (NSString *) cellLabelString
  {

  for (id subview in self.contentView.subviews) {
      [subview removeFromSuperview];
  }

//rest of init

}

Hope that helps.

**EDIT** 
I better way of doing this is to override prepareForReuse in Custom table view cell class and set the values to nil. It might not be the recommended method, but I haven't experienced any performance issue.

Comment: Hi, I haven't tested this since I found another solution, but thanks a lot for your answer, this may help someone else